# create new elements from object values in click handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a settings object with keys and values made up of booleans, arrays, or numbers.

```
const settings = {
  test1: true,
  test2: ["1", "2"],
  test3: 80
}
```

I render the keys like this:

```
  const renderSettings = () =>
    Object.keys(settings).map((entry, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={`setting-${index}`}>
          <span>{entry}</span>
        </li>
      );
    });
```

The parent `<ul>` has a click handler attached to it. When the user clicks on a setting, the code first checks that the key really exists on the settings object, and then attempts to get the subset of options.

Question: How do I render/return newly created value `spans` based on the subset of data?

Example: User clicks on the test1 `<li>`, the code checks what subset of data exists on the key, sees it's an array, and should create both `1` and `2` as a span. Nothing happens for me with the following code:

```
const [savedOptions, setSavedOptions] = useState([]);

const handleClick = (e) => {
  const target = e.target; (e.g. <li>1</li>)
  const value = e.target.innerHTML; (e.g. 1)

  e.preventDefault();

  target.classList.toggle("selected");

  if (savedOptions.indexOf(value) === -1) {
    setSavedOptions([...savedOptions, value]);

    for (let key in options) {
      options[key].map((el) => {
        return <span>{el}</span>;
      });
    }
  } else {
    setSavedOptions(savedOptions.filter((entry) => entry !== value));
  }
};
```

Is there an easier way than document.createElement.... Am I over complicating things? How do I return new elements from a click handler?
I am also getting all console.logs twice in the console, but that's an entirely different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before you proceed with this solution , fix your errors !

*options or savedOptions ?*

```
for (let key in options) {
      options[key].map((el) => {
        return <span>{el}</span>;
      });
    }
```

The above map function returns spans but how will it render ? i created an displaySubset state that holds the subset spans and renders if it exists on the render method . im not 100% accurate but you should make the handleClick function store the subset spans in state and show them in render function !

```
const [displaySubset,setDisplaySubset]=useState([]);
    
    const handleClick = (e) => {
      let elements=[]
      const target = e.target; (e.g. <li>1</li>)
      const value = e.target.innerHTML; (e.g. 1)
    
      e.preventDefault();
    
      target.classList.toggle("selected");
    
      if (savedOptions.indexOf(value) === -1) {
        setSavedOptions([...savedOptions, value]);
    
        for (let key in savedOptions) {
          options[key].map((el) => {
            elements.push( <span>{el}</span>)
          });
        }
        setDisplaySubset(elements)
      } else {
        setSavedOptions(savedOptions.filter((entry) => entry !== value));
      }
    };
    
    
    const renderSettings = () =>
        Object.keys(settings).map((entry, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={`setting-${index}`}>
              <span>{entry}</span>
            </li>
            {displaySubset}
            ()
          );
        });
```